# Mobile p5js vertex on pgraphics will draw with auto weight line

Tags: p5.js

my p5js paint tool not working well on mobile (web and web-app)
you can test drawing in [here](https://is2you2.github.io/pjcone_pwa/?voidDraw=%5B%5D)
(This page work well on Desktop, please test on mobile devices)

---

Infos:

Test devices:
Google pixel 6 (oriole)
LineageOS 20
Android 13

PWA test on mobile chrome browser failed but on desktop work well

This is ionic framework project and use npm p5 ("p5": "^1.7.0",)

---

drawing code looks like this:

```js
...

// this code run after input released(mouse or touch)
// before release input (means on drawing), will draw on canvas (p5.Renderer) after every layer drawn
// so, you can see "on drawing" line works well
let updateDrawingCurve = (TargetCanvas: p5.Graphics, targetDraw = CurrentDraw) => {
  TargetCanvas.push();
  TargetCanvas.translate(CropPosition);
  TargetCanvas.stroke(targetDraw['color']); // p5.Color
  TargetCanvas.strokeWeight(targetDraw['weight']); // float
  TargetCanvas.beginShape();
  // targetDraw['pos'] data form: p5.Vector[]
  for (let i = 0, j = targetDraw['pos'].length; i < j; i++)
    TargetCanvas.curveVertex(targetDraw['pos'][i].x, targetDraw['pos'][i].y);
  TargetCanvas.endShape();
  TargetCanvas.pop();
  TargetCanvas.redraw();
  p.redraw();
}

...
```

both platform (mobile and desktop) use same code

---

It consists of the following:
[image: layer]
every user input will draw vertex in red layer

---

I found:

- draw vertex on p5.Renderer (canvas) will work well on mobile but on p5.Graphics is not
  [image: sample_pc]
  (this is sample draw on pc, mobile drawing on canvas(p5.Renderer) has same result)
- draw vertex on p5.Graphics will work unexpected
  [image: sample_mobile]
  (this is sample draw on mobile which is drawing on p5.Grahpics / on mobile)

Any ideas or suggestions to solve this problem?
Thank you

I believe this is a problem that cannot be solved using only p5js (means high-level).

I expected same result on mobile-pwa and desktop-pwa

and mobile-pwa work different

---

This is runnable minimal reproducible example code.
https://editor.p5js.org/is2you2/sketches/3TFtukC4x

same result: It is OK on desktop, not OK on mobile

Comment: Please share all relevant code in the question itself as a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: After listening to what you said and reproducing the sample code, I found that it worked normally. And my project is still not working correctly. I will update the post once I am able to reproduce the error. I think it will take longer than I thought.

Comment: FWIW your p5 sketch (editor link above) works on iOS 17.2.1. Perhaps the issue with other smartphones (Android) and/or particular version of the OS ? (Does it make a difference if you make `pg` a 2D Canvas instead of `WEBGL` ?)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The runnable code should be in the question itself (there's [no need to say "EDIT 1:"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged)).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza if pgraphics uses P2D, 'You are trying to use setAttributes on a p5.Graphics object that does not use a WEBGL renderer.' logs appear on log. so i use WEBGL. However, as you said, using P2D, the pen thickness is drawn as expected !
Some code modifications related to translate() are needed, but I think this will solve the problem. thank you

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your kind explanation. I was able to become a better person :)